# Suffix available in php

Tags: php

Hello eveyone i am trying to find a list of **suffix available in php** such as .php/.phtml, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: @vlad: no, it's a webserver directive. There's no such thing as a "php script" or "php file". There's only files which have php code blocks (`<?php ... ?>`) embedded in them. You could, if you wanted to, embed php code into a .jpg file. As long as the webserver's been told to run a particular file extension through the php interpreter, it'll execute the code.

Comment: My bad, deleted my comment. Thank you for clarifying that, I knew something, but not the whole story :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- .php
- .php3
- .php4
- .php5
- .phtml
- .html
- .asp
- .john
- .whatever.

It all depends on how your server is configured.

Comment: I like the suspense curve of this answer :)

Comment: Even without extension... if configured.

Comment: Thank you John do you have a guide so i can learn how to configure the engine?....

Answer (score 0):

This is generally done in the Apache config file - httpd.conf (in my case on a unix system located at /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf)

see point 8 of http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

From my config:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .wphp
```

You can also use mod_rewrite to have say a html url/link parsed by PHP without changing the apache config just by editing the .htaccess file, for example:

```
# normal job link http://example.com/design/design_manager.JOB406359.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.JOB([0-9]+)\.html$                  php/view_job.php?job_id=$2  [L]
```